# How to solve integral with min in boundary?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve [this probability question](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_5_solved_prob.php):

> Let X and Y be jointly continuous random variables with joint PDF:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

> Find P(Y < 2 * X^2)

The solution says the integral should be:

[image: solution]

btu while I understand *why* there is a "min" in the bounds of the integral, I don't understand the rest of the integration.

For example: Why aren't we integrating `3x+1` and instead are just multiplying by the upper bound of the integral?

Would appreciate if someone can explain the steps.

Comment: better to use mathjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\int_0^{\min(2x^2,1-x)}3x+1\,\mathrm dy\tag1$$is an integral with respect to $y$. But there is no $y$ in $3x+1$. So, since we always have $\int_a^bc\,\mathrm dx=c(b-a)$, $(1)$ is equal to $\bigl(\min(2x^2,1-x)-0\bigr)(3x+1)$.